# Simple 2 screen navigation in MvvmCross android app breaks back-button

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-emulator, mvvmcross

I have made a very simple project using the latest MvvmCross version (4.2.3) in which i have 2 android screens: FirstView and SecondView. I use a button on FirstView to navigate to SecondView:

```
// FirstView.cs
private void PrepareShowSecondButton()
{
    var hero = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.firstview_show_second_button);
    hero.Text = DreamsResources.FirstView_ShowSecond_Button_Label;
    BindingSet.Bind(hero).To(vm => vm.ShowSecondCommand);
    BindingSet.Apply();
}


// FirstViewModel.cs
private MvxCommand _showSecondCommand;

public MvxCommand ShowSecondCommand
{
    get
    {
        _showSecondCommand = _showSecondCommand ?? new MvxCommand(DoShowSecondCommand);
        return _showSecondCommand;
    }
}

private void DoShowSecondCommand()
{
    ShowViewModel<SecondViewModel>(new SecondViewModelBundle() { Data = "Hello from FirstView - " + Hello });
}
```

However, when I use the backbutton on the android device, and click the button to show SecondView again, SecondView is added multiple times (5-6) to the navigation stack. I have to click the back button so many times to get back to FirstView.

Code:

```
public class SecondViewModel : DreamsViewModelBase
{
    private readonly IDreamsWebService _webService;

    public SecondViewModel(IDreamsWebService webService)
    {
        _webService = webService;
    }

    public void Init(SecondViewModelBundle bundle)
    {
        Log.Log("Initializing with data: " + bundle.Data);
        SecondData = bundle.Data;
    }

    private string _secondData;

    public string SecondData
    {
        get { return _secondData; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _secondData, value, "SecondData"); }
    }
}
```

Layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/activity_firstview_top_container_coordinatorlayout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    local:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/firstview_content_container_linearlayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/firstview_edittext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="40dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstview_textview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="40dp" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/firstview_show_second_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

How do i avoid SecondView being added to the navigation stack multiple times? I've even tried setting the activity flag "SingleTop" which seems like a bad solution, and didnt even work.

Comment: The code doesn´t look wrong to me. The only thing I can think of is that you are calling `PrepareShowSecondButton` several times, duplicating the binding. That would open the second view as many times as the number of of bindings applied to "hero" button

Comment: Can you show the complete `FirstView` and `FirstViewModel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your project at GitHub you are calling the `PrepareUI` method on the `onResume` activity lifecycle callback. This adds (stacks) the same bindings every time the `FirstView` has been resumed (first time the app is opened, every time `SecondView` is closed). Thus, you end up with multiple bindings on the Show SecondViewModel button, which leads to opening the viewmodel several times.

There isn't a provided method that will clear the bindings, but you can do other things:

1. create a new `BindingSet` object
2. call your `PrepareUI` in the `onCreate` method